# WebIDE refuses to connect to KaiOS device

Tags: kaios

I recently bought an Alcatel Smartflip phone. I have been having trouble trying to get WebIDE to work. Steps I have tried are these:

1. use `*#*#33284#*#*` on the phone so the little bug appears in the status bar on the phone.
2. open terminal and use `adb devices`. Device is shown. (adb shell works)
3. Tried Palemoon browser WebIDE and clicked on `Remote Runtime`. Default is localhost:6000.

-- Get Error: Operation Failed: Connecting to remote runtime --

4. Tried `adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket`

-- Same Error --

5. Tried the KaioSRT and see device listed.

-- Get the same error --

6. Checked stack overflow. Appears I may need to run `xhost +` in terminal.

-- Same Errors --

I'm at a loss of what else to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try step 4 first then step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an older version of Mozilla Firefox (version 57.0.1 or so). You can download it from their FTP server: https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

You can also take help from the following setup guides:

1. https://developer.kaiostech.com/getting-started/env-setup/os-env-setup
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI-HW2cLrew&t=38s

Comment: It appears that my phone is a "locked phone". It is impossible to get WebIDE to work on it according to BananaHackers.net